# I have an Arduino with multiple sensors and want to know the total current/power consumption of the system

Tags: arduino, batteries

I have 3 PIR sensors, a piezo buzzer, 3 simple LED's, the Arduino system, and 2 temp. sensors. I plan on using a 9 volt battery and implementing sleep mode during the running of the system. What methods can I use to figure out how much current is passing through the system and find the power consumption? Also, can you direct me to a site for a battery management system to determine how much potential the 9 volt battery would have at different stages?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for characterization purposes when you're testing the device, you can just use the current measurement feature on your multimeter. Place the meter between the positive terminal of the 9V battery and the supply input to your circuit.

If it's for online monitoring (ie: as a feature of the device), the easiest thing is probably a current sensing shunt resistor and an instrumentation amplifier chip. Current sense resistors are available in various values, but something like 0.05 ohms is probably sufficient for your application. The differential inputs of the instrumentation amp go across the current sense resistor, and the output goes to one of the Arduino's analog pins.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f28c4l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Voltage across the current sense resistor just comes from Ohm's law (V=IR). Use your maximum expected current to determine the gain setting for the instrumentation amplifier. For example, if you want to measure a maximum of 500 mA current, 0.05 ohms * 500 mA = 25mV, so a gain factor of 200 will scale this parameter to 0-5V for the Arduino's ADC.

As for the next part of your question - once again, if it's just for characterization purposes, use a multimeter. You can find the characteristic curves of a 9V battery pretty easily on Google (for example, [here's a datasheet from Duracell](http://ww2.duracell.com/media/en-US/pdf/gtcl/Product_Data_Sheet/NA_DATASHEETS/MN1604_6LR61_US_CT.pdf)). If it's for online monitoring, just use a voltage divider to scale the 0-9V voltage to 0-5V for the Arduino ADC. Actually, I'd probably just use a divide-by-two voltage divider for a little headroom at the top end. The circuit is simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2HVeA.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do hardware, the first thing you need to do is buy a DMM (digital multimeter), and make sure you get one with a current function. Then you hook up your components to a 9-volt power supply and measure the current being delivered to the load. If you can't do that, find the data sheets for each part, and they should list the approximate supply current. Add them up.

As for the behavior of a 9-volt battery, Google "9 volt battery capacity". You obviously have internet access. Use it.